# Best way to create fantokens

Tags: tokens

Some football clubs issued own fantokens

And I'm wondering if there is an infrastructure for mass creation of crypto fantokens, for example by blogers

1. What service can offer a user-friendly interface to generate own tokens? (preferably Ethereum-based)
2. Does the service which also can provide manually set up a quarterly token dividends for holders exist?